# Versioning issue when using jersey 2.9 with tomcat7 + java8

Tags: tomcat7, java-8, jersey-2.0, maven-tomcat-plugin

We have a maven project to develop a jersey 2.0 REST service, on Eclipse (kepler)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In conjunction with:

- java8
- tomcat7

When deploying the web application (using `$ mvn install && mvn -X tomcat7:redeploy`) we get the below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2840)
```

1. I examined the MANIFEST file in the org.glassfish.jersey.containers jar, and (as suspected) it says build on 1.7 JDK
2. Tomcat logs confirm that it uses java8 itself

We cannot move back to java8.  Is there a way/hack we can get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

From tomcat 7.0.26, I upgraded to next version > Tomcat 7.0.47, to see if that helps. 
Things started working magically. Deployed app successfully

Would be glad if someone can explain how the same plugin started to ignore jdk versions, just due to a change in tomcat version.